# Will my laptop support HDMI HD resolution if it doesn't support VGA bigger than 1280x1024?

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi, external-display

I have an issue with using external display on my Acer travel mate 5742G with Windows 7.
I have connected it to my montor through VGA and it cannot get bigger resolution than 1280x1024 while having 1366x768 on my kaptop display.

Here arises my question: will my laptop support higher resolutions if I connect the monitor to the laptop through HDMI cable ? 
Anyone has some experience with that ?

BTW my graphics card is Nvidia GeForce GT 420M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a HDMI out port, then yes it should support higher resolutions.

[From the Nvidia website](http://www.geforce.com/Hardware/NotebookGPUs/geforce-gt-420m/features) for your Graphics chip

> Dual-link DVI Support
>
> Able to drive industry’s largest and highest resolution flat-panel displays up to 2560x1600 and with support for High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection

But they also say:

> Graphics card specifications may vary by Add-in-card manufacturer. Please refer to the Add-in-card manufacturers' website for actual shipping specifications.

I cannot find the video specifications [on the Acer site](http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx?tab=4&modelId=3308) unfortunately. It may not have the HDMI dual link support if Acer did not implement it, so the max resolution may be lower.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try conntacting Nvidia support then :) Hopefully they will help.

Comment: HDMI is not Dual-Link DVI.  All HDMI/DVI adapters work with a single-link signal only.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, the type of cable won't make a difference because the limitation is in the graphics chipset's processing capability. I've had a few integrated Nvidia graphics chipsets that had the same limitation. You might be able to increase the resolution by decreasing the color depth, however.

Another option would be to use an USB to HDMI adapter like [this one](http://www.meritline.com/mygica-ushow-1080p-usb-graphic-adapter-dvi-output---p-42351.aspx) instead of using the laptop's built-in VGA or HDMI output.